# How I can I get all the user info using react typescript and redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using react typescript with redux toolkit and in order to get user Info I've got stuck  .
this a userSlice.ts:

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
   
  },
});
```

this is part of protectedRoute.tsx :

```
export function ProtectedRoute(props: { children: any }) {
  const {user} = useSelector((state: any) => state.user);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(showLoading());
      const response = await axios.post(
        "/api/users/user",
        { token: localStorage.getItem("token") },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
          },
        }
      );
      dispatch(hideLoading());
      if (response.data.success) {
        console.log(response.data.data.isAdmin);
        dispatch(setUser(response.data.data));
```

the problem is state.user can take only one value I want to register all the data from the backend.

How Can I make  that

Comment: What do you exatcly mean by "can take only one value"? Could you provide an example of a value it cannot take

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do u mean by state.user can take only one value ?
If you mean You want to store all the data from the server regarding user you can also turn the user into a type with expected object and pass the whole response object.
i.e

```
type User = {
  isAdmin: boolean,
  ...
}

initialState: {
  user: User,
},
```

Comment: it will not work because User is a type not value